# Long wait time on login

Tags: server, ssh, performance, login

When I log in on my server I get this:

```
No mail.
Last login: Fri Nov  5 14:22:45 2010...
```

then I must wait for 5 sec and then is ready...

```
wolfy@ubuntu-server:~$
```

Is this wait time normal or should I do something to "repair" this?

Comment: Are you using the ssh option keepalive ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is usually the result of `pam_motd` regenerating the `/etc/motd` file. You can check the individual scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` to see if something is especially slow.

Comment: Brilliant.  It was the file 90-updates-available for me.  Also 50-landscape-sysinfo is not the most speedy.

Answer (score 13):

I have the same issues with 10.04 (LTS).

When I run my ssh with `-vvv`, it dies at:

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

---

Extending this answer.

I managed to reboot the server remotely and enabled DEBUG loggin. Also used this opportunity to stay logged in and observe other login attempts. Here is what happens. The client connects and is authorized and hangs at above message.

On the server, the process list shows this:

```
root       835  0.0  0.1  11476  3348 ?        Ss   13:39   0:00 sshd: till [priv]
root       840  0.0  0.0   4804  1124 ?        S    13:39   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /bin/run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
root       841  0.0  0.0   4728  1108 ?        S    13:39   0:00 /bin/run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
root       854  0.0  0.0   4804  1144 ?        S    13:39   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo
root       861  0.2  0.5  15388  9248 ?        S    13:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo
root       863  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:39   0:00 [who] <defunct>
```

I can execute `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo` just fine while I am logged in, but for some reason, I cannot figure out why it stalls the login process. When I kill the process, the login continues to the prompt and is *successful*.

This doesn't seem to be an ssh(d) problem, it's more related to `update-motd` and landscape. I uninstalled the `update-motd` package, but it seems like the `/etc/update-motd` directory persists and the scripts are still executed - causing the process to hang.

---

Debuging this further:

Turns out the `/etc/update-motd.d/` directory doesn't really belong to the package `update-motd`, it seems to be triggered by pam authentication through sshd.

---

**I seem to have nailed it!**

Disabled pam_motd in the following files:

- /etc/pam.d/sshd
- /etc/pam.d/login

---

One more:

```
apt-get purge landscape-client landscape-common
```

These seem to help to a certain extend. Though, it *only* removes the offending script in `/etc/update-motd.d/` and neither deletes all scripts in that directory nor does it get rid off `pam_motd` either.

In general, I found no way to disable `pam_motd` completely because it seems, whatever it does – it slows down the login process to a certain extend. It doesn't block like the script in `landscape-common`, but it is slower.

Bug report on this issue:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/805423

Workarounds from there:

> You are right that the ability to log in is more important than
>   presenting a motd. If this behavior is a problem for you, there are
>   several ways that you can disable it:
>
> - comment out the 'pam_motd' line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` if you don't want to display a motd.
> - delete the contents of the `/etc/update-motd.d` directory.
> - chmod -x the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` that you don't want to run.

Answer (score 10):

Found solution myself finally:

1. `sudo apt-get remove landscape-client landscape-common`
2. comment line
   `session optional pam_motd.so`
   in `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

Now login is INSTANT!

Comment: looks like some network issue was holding the stats up?

Answer (score 4):

From your description it sounds more like a networking problem. To diagnose:

- Run ssh with the -v parameter to be verbose.
- Try running a ping to the SSH server you're connecting to, and see if this also hangs at the same time.
- Try some other kind of transfer to the same server. For instance, wget with the --limit-rate parameter to fetch a file through HTTP and have it take long enough that it may trigger the "hanging" behavior.
- See whether it hangs only when idle, or even if you're doing something at the moment. If it hangs while idle, the -v diagnostics will probably tell you so, in which case the advice to use keepalive could help (ssh -o "TCPKeepAlive yes")

If you can connect OK with Windows and PuTTY, it's probably not an issue on the server's side.

Answer (score 3):

If `PermitEmptyPassword` and `UsePAM` are both enabled, OpenSSH server always attempts authentication with a null password, which it takes as a sign that no authentication is needed for the account in question. It does this as soon as the authentication process begins, in both protocols, and not in response any "real" authentication request
from the client. OpenSSH will only allow such access if the sshd_config
flag `PermitEmptyPassword` is set; unfortunately, the way the code is
written, it performs the password test in any case, and thus shows up to
PAM as a failure.

So: disable `PermitEmptyPassword` or `UsePAM`, but remember: **without PAM, wou won't be able to login without a key.**

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.security.ssh/wExY8lWlG-c

Comment: I've added this answer to this old question because I came into the same problem (slow login), but nothing here solved my problem. This is my solution.

Comment: Had to disable both settings

Answer (score 2):

I think when you login, ubuntu executes one or more of these files:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
```

You could see what's in them and maybe even try executing them to see what's taking so long.

Answer (score 2):

In my limited experience, when putty works, but Linux, Ubuntu in this case, does not, it is usually keep alive. Networking or server problems would affect both client OS.

You can use the above keep alive option on the command line, but it is sort of tedious to type.

Easier to edit a few configuration files.

If you have `root access`, and wish to enable it automatically for all users, edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` , add

```
KeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

If you do not have root access, or to enable it for a single user, edit `~/.ssh/config` and add the same two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system logs at /var/log, you may find a message with the related error/timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to monitor the running processes while you're logging in to the server from an already logged-in connection (or a different console). There is a chance to spot which processes are the most active or using the most CPU at that time.

Below is one possible method:

1. Try to log in on an other console.
2. Run `top` there to see what happens.
3. Log in on the 1st console.

Please note, that if the delay is not caused by some CPU-intensive calculation, you will not spot anything out-of-place. This case the problem might be I/O bound (waiting for some disk read/write or network response).

Comment: top shows this(on login):

12112 sshd      20   0  6988  856  412 S 13.9  0.1   0:00.42 sshd

Comment: @Idi, I think this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have also a time wait before

Edit `/etc/sshd_config`

and set (or add)

```
UseDNS no
```

or add your ip in `/etc/hosts` if its a static local one