# How to speed up SSH login using a public key and PuTTY?

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long wait time on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11538/long-wait-time-on-login)

I am using PuTTY to log into my local server, but it takes about 1.5 seconds to log in (from the click on 'Connect' to working command prompt, most of time is spend on "Authenticating with public key...").

I know many see even slower speeds, but I would like to have not more than 0.1 sec. login time.

I already set `UseDNS=no`, allowed only IPv4 in the PuTTY client, and reduced key length from 4k down to 1k.

Any other suggestions to speed it up even further?