# SSH hangs about a minute after login

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long wait time on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11538/long-wait-time-on-login)

I am connecting from a Ubuntu Desktop 11.10 to a Ubuntu Server 11.10, over SSH using public key authentication.  Problem is within about a minute after logging in, the connection hangs.  I've seen it happen once while in vi and a few times while just at the prompt.  Connecting from Windows 7 using Putty seems to work fine, so I'm thinking it's a problem with my SSH client on my Ubuntu desktop or the an issue with the public key pair.

Any advice on how I can troubleshoot?

Thanks in advance.