# Does Ubuntu (server) go to sleep? Why does it take long to login?

Tags: server, login, openssh, sshd

I have several Ubuntu Server (12.04 LTS) virtual machines.  Some are idle and some are processing background tasks, etc.

However, when I try to login (SSH) to the servers, it often takes several seconds but subsequent login (within a short amount of time) are very quick which makes me think the server is going to sleep after a certain amount of idle time.

(This might be my virtual server [ESXi] causing this, but I haven't found anything...)

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/11538/long-wait-time-on-login?rq=1 it might help

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that come to mind that it could be:

- A bios power management system that is causing a sleep mode
- Hard drive spin up time

Although the chances of those options are low given that they are virtual machines... unless they are located on another drive. I dont believe that Ubuntu server has a sleep mode active by default, although it is possible to allow it to sleep.