# restarting ssh, wifi and related processes

Tags: server, wireless, ssh, suspend, restart

Often when I am connected to a remote server using `ssh` I am unable to `ssh` into the same server again after the connection got interrupted. (For example by my laptop suspending.)

Restarting the laptop seems to fix the issue. Is there a way to restart all the related services as if I restarted my laptop without having to fully restart the laptop.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

---

When the ssh fails it just hangs after the ssh command without any error message.

For the ssh problem: ssh --vvv outputs:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for login.hpc.clustername.ext
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 28085
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
```

Comment: Whatever is easiest. I imagine re-initializing as if restarting is much easier then to fix a complex problem with some wrongly left over setting/value, but of course I am interested in any solution.

Comment: Well I believe the problem I want to solve is clear an answerable. My question is about simply replicating a restart for processes that might be relevant (which can probably be limited to things directly related to ssh and wifi). The question you are proposing is probably dependent on server details, ssh settings and many things that will be hard to find and include into the question. (Thanks for the suggestion though.)

Comment: Good point. Should have included that info. Will edit. No error message. It just hangs (before the step where it would usually) ask for a password.

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/344863/ssh-new-connection-begins-to-hang-not-reject-or-terminate-after-a-day-or-so-on for a similar-seeming problem and couple solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Next time it occurs I will ssh with -vvv and see whether the most upvoted answer might apply for me. Note that also in this case the only solution that actually worked for the OP was to reboot (https://askubuntu.com/a/363830/800252). So it is not that strange to be asking for a solution in that direction.